# How to split base64 string data to chunks less than 1 mb for aws kinesis put stream api?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I am trying to send data of blob by converting into base 64 but my base 64 data is more than 9mb for each interval of video. I need to split that data to less than 1 megabyte to send it to kinesis put stream. please help if any one of you has created an algorithm to split base 64 data into chunks less than 1 megabyte?

Comment: Can you describe what you want to do with the videos? Did you consider using Kinesis Video Stream?

Comment: no i dont need kinesis video stream. i am transferring blob of video to kinesis data stream. but kinesis data stream have limit of 1mb persecond and my blob size is more than 7 mb , i have to convert and split it into chunks

Comment: What is the destination of the video data? S3?